# IE11 HTML entity rendering font not inherited?

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-11

Ohhh Internet Explorer...

I'm attempting to render the HTML Entity (Decimal/Hexadecimal) for Celsius / Fahrenheit values within the DOM, easy right? Unfortunately not... I've noticed that through IE11 (WIN 8.1) testing, the `font-family` designation for the container of the HTML entity is being ignored, and the browser is rendering it *oddly* (see below).

I'm wondering what type of quirk might be producing this as I'm unable to track down the root cause at the moment. Any help would be appreciated!

**Visuals:**

- [Chrome – Mac High Sierra (`65`)](https://image.prntscr.com/image/ivwlNJ4dQyG4BoGX6ackcQ.png)
- [IE11 – Windows 8.1 (`Latest`)](https://image.prntscr.com/image/SBzwN8YeS-Ox6PhuqV91kQ.png)

**Demonstrations:**

- https://codepen.io/jodriscoll/pen/OvGeRd

---

```
<style>
    body {
      margin: 40px;
    }

    div {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    span {
      font-family: "Open Sans", Arial Unicode MS;
      font-size: 14px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 30px;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <span>24&#8457;</span>
    <span>24&#x2109;</span>
    <hr/>
    <span>42&#8451;</span>
    <span>42&#x2103;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good from IE11 https://imgur.com/FrYEypx

Comment: @zer00ne – Interesting... I was using BrowserStack Windows 8.1 IE11 (Latest). What version of Windows/IE are you testing against?

Comment: Win 10 /  IE 11.731.16299.0 / Update version: 11.0.60 (KB4092946). I'm not familiar with SASS but does `Arial Unicode MS` need to be wrapped in quotes as well?

Comment: @zer00ne – darn, this appears to be an IE11 Windows 8.1 isolated issue. You could actually drop that as a fallback, but it doesn't require wrapping quotations. I was testing that out, but it didn't appear to change the outcome at all.

Comment: Browser inconsistencies are a pain but OS is just plain awful, my sympathies, sir. Maybe `::after` `content: \2103` and `\2109`?

Comment: Putting quotes around font names is always strongly recommended,  not so much because of the spaces in them, but more because the browser tries to interpret the individual words as keywords first.

Comment: Anyway, the solution seems to be to explicitly use a font that does include the ℉ character. (On Windows, see the Charmap application).